# How to correctly pass in function and arguments to typescript function?

Tags: typescript

I am trying pass two functions as parameters to another function and passing arguments. The compiled JavaScript is working as expected. But I am getting an error from TypeScript. Here's the code and error:

```
function func1(name: string) {
  return name;
}

function func2(age: number) {
  return age;
}

type Func = typeof func1 | typeof func2;

function func3(func: Func, arg: string | number) {
  return func(arg); 
  // Error for `arg` in above line: 
  // Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}

const x = func3(func1, 'hello');
const y = func3(func2, 5);

console.log('x', x);
console.log('y', y);
```

What would be the correct way to type the above? Please note that I am trying not to make the `func` argument of `func3` to be completely generic, but to be only of type `func1` or `func2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to avoid your function being called incorrectly like `func3(func1, 5)`. I suggest using a generic type parameter:

```
function func3<T extends string | number>(func: (arg: T) => T, arg: T) {
  return func(arg);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSBGAFGAhgWwKYBciAzlAE4xgDmAlIgN4BQiiZeUIZS2+A3IwF9GjFNHhJRAJnRYqhRGBA4ARnjJ0mLNhy6JZefkMZQAngAc8iAGLgIiALyJTFuMGS3UiAD5PzeV+6QkvwitrAIgRAAzAA8ACqIeAAeUHhgACbEJOSUVN4KSqpkAHzookQyZFREcXT2xYhxADR6VTUazKzsnBK2lbSGwhAIpIhJDpFRZR4tAOQAFngANktwszT8w2CjJhOiU1ItAKwbQyNQiWRke7YHM4gnvIgA9M+XZHBkLVhZbACOIBgbHSjCAA)

Comment: Thank you @kaya3 :) I am trying not to make the `func` argument of `func3` to be completely generic, but to be only of type `func1` or `func2`. Is it possible to do so? I will also update the question.

Comment: @adam You can give `T` an upper bound of `string | number`; I've edited the answer to reflect this. There might technically be something more you could do but I think it would be unnecessary and probably very messy.